# How to add up button besides the hamburger icon in android toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to add up button besides the hamburger icon which opens my navigation drawer. I want the user to be able to navigate to the parent activity if he clicks the up button. is it possible? I want something like this, although this screenshot is of iOS.

[image]

Comment: Consider Using `Fragments` , the parent activity must implement the `Navigation Drawer`

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible, Android lets you add button on action bar to the right of it. Drawer menu show 1 button, which you can set it to be an arrow (showHomeAsUp(true)) or the burger menu

Comment: would you please elaborate? Also, the nature of my application is such, that i have to use separate activities (all of which share a common navigation drawer) instead of fragments.